# Why is the irrationality of $\gamma$ so ellusive? (Euler–Mascheroni constant)

Tags: irrational-numbers, constants, euler-mascheroni-constant, rationality-testing, provability

Perhaps I'm in way over my head asking this; regardless, considering the abundance of known formulas and properties of [$\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), seemingly comparable in quantity to the likes of $\pi$ or $e$, why is the irrationality of such so hard to prove?

In other words, what exactly makes the surrounding mysteries of the constant out of reach of present-day mathematics? Or is the mystery a mystery in itself?

I note that [user571036](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/571036/user571036) asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834788/irrationality-of-the-euler-mascheroni-constant), but specifically surrounding one method of proving it's irrationality (using it's relationship to the harmonic series).

Comment: I am no expert on these topics, but I have heard people who are more knowledgeable say that we are basically not good at proving irrationality. We get lucky with $e$, and $\pi$ and $e$ are related by algebraic numbers by $e^{i \pi}  = -1$ - so we get $\pi$ for free.

Comment: $\gamma\ $ is not the only number without known character : We do not know for each of the numbers $\ e+\pi\ $ and $e\cdot\pi\ $ , whether they are irrational, we only know that at least one of them must be transcedental. Irrationality proof are extremely difficult in general. For $\ e\ $, the taylor-expansion happens to give an easy proof, but already for $\ \pi\ $ , much more effort is needed.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey The irrationality of $\ \pi\ $ was proven without this result, later the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem allowed this easy alternative even allowing to show that $\ e\ $ and $\ \pi\ $ are transcendental. Lambert used the continued fraction of the arctan-function to show that $\ \pi\ $ is irrational.

Comment: Because there is no fast converging series for it with number theoretically transparent coefficients.

Comment: It is said that Erdoes offered his job to a person being able to prove that $\ \gamma\ $ is irrational, he must have been very convinced that this is out of reach. Fun note : I found a wrong proof in a published paper using the fact that the partial sum $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n)$ is irrational for every $n$ , which is in fact true. The limit is in fact $\ \gamma\ $ , but the conclusion that therefore $\ \gamma\ $ must be irrational is false , this was actually used in this "proof".

Comment: The partial sum is in fact only irrational for $n>1$. I had no time anymore to edit this.

Comment: Erdoes never had a permanent job. So he could not offer it.

Comment: @JCAA As I understood it, he would have given his job away, I do not know it he would have been forced if someone would have found it out. I think noone knows , whether this was only a joke , or a great believe in the impossibility. Whatever it was, Erdoes turned out to be right until now.

Comment: That claim about Erdos is most probably fake unless you can present any evidense.

Comment: @JCAA Maybe, there is no need for me to prove this claim because in my comment I said "it is said"